# MVC3 DisplayFor() customized price

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to display customised price from Model.price on page.
I want to display the price like Model.price * 3%
How can I make it? When I trying to do like this, it has errors.

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.price * 0.3)
```

How can I display particular price?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to modify your model to include a ModifiedPrice property that does the calculation.

```
public class myproduct {
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
    public decimal ModifiedPrice { get { return Price * 0.3; } }
{

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ModifiedPrice)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, and when I put get { return Price * 0.3; }, I have got error, 'Operator * cannot be applied to operands type 'decimal' and 'double'. How can I do?

Comment: use 0.3M instead.  This is basic C# type stuff, if you don't know how types work, you shouldn't be doing more advanced things.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I need to study more and more.. anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have options here:

If this is a one time thing, you may want to do it as below:

```
@(Model.price * 0.3)
```

You may want to centralize this and use it as below. You can put this inside **Decimal.cshtml** file under **~\Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates**:

```
@model decimal
@(ViewData.Model * 0.3)
```

The usage of the second one is as usual. It will pick it up:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.price)
```